# Is moist heat therapy preferable to dry heat for pain relief due to arthritis, myofibrosis, back pain, muscle strains and spasms?

Tags: medical-science

[https://www.amazon.com/Chattanooga-Original-Hydrocollator-Therapy-HotPac/dp/B01ALJE8J8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ALJE8J8) ([mirror](http://archive.is/7IcRH)) claims:

> Benefits of moist heat therapy over dry heat are well established for pain relief due to arthritis, myofibrosis, back pain, muscle strains and spasms.

Has any scientific study confirmed that claim?

Comment: What exactly is "moist" heat? Like hot bath vs heat pack? Just the presence of water?

Comment: Since arthritis is an inflammation and leads to warmth of the affected joint, surely _cooling_ is required, not heat at all. ?